# Cклонение названия улицы Республики

Tags: склонение

Как правильно: Дом на Республики или Дом на Республике?

Comment: Уточните, что такое Республика.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны, ни один не ошибочен.

Итак, исходное (хотя и странноватое) - некая улица Республики.

В случае "Дом на Республики" честно ("паспортно") произнесено название улицы, но само слово "улица" опущено. Разговорное. Норма.

А "Дом на Республике" - можно спорить, просторечное или тоже разговорное, я склоняюсь к последнему. Улицу убрали как класс, мол, само собой разумеется, обозначают только республику (имени которой). Ну и, соответственно, склоняют.

Comment: В предложном падеже исключительно окончание "е". Отсутствие слова "улица", которое **входит в название** (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Улица_Республики), не даёт права на согласование в другом падеже. Да и звучит дико. Вывод: слово из названия пропускать нельзя. (Дизлайк не мой.)

Comment: Спасибо, oleedd. Давно за тобой наблюдаю - свой и в теме. А для дизлайков существуют всякие малограмотные провокаторы-бегемоты... у которых улицы на станциях... выдуманный такой фантасмагорический мир и такой же язык. Но как же ж - низзя?! Сказать-то всяко-разно можно. А стало быть, и отобразить.

Answer (score 1):

Никак не правильно.
Подобные сомнительные случаи нельзя употреблять без родового слова.

Только в России есть несколько городов, где есть "Улица Республики" (Тюмень, Сургут).
Есть как минимум один (Буинск, Татарстан) с "улицей Республика". И несколько с улицами "Республика Советов" и подобными.

И это только улицы. А ещё районы, станции...

И если вариант "улица Республика" еще с грехом пополам может быть представлен без родового слова ("дом на Республике"), то "тюменский" вариант ("на Республики") полностью такое исключает. По причине уже того, что страшно выглялит.

Пишите уж хотя бы "дом на ул. Республики"

Answer (score 1):

В изначально *письменных* текстах ни то, ни другое наименование, конечно, *недопустимы*. Однако неформальная *устная* ссылка на столь нетипичное название улицы (любая из двух) возможна, причём только между людьми (в данном случае, местными), понимающими, о чём речь (без уточнений и вопрос был непонятен). При письменном воспроизводстве такой речи (напр. интервью, данного местному журналисту) нужно считаться с тем, что аудитория может оказаться относительно широкой, и вставить в прямую речь пояснение от редакции (напр. "на [ул. - *примеч. редакции*] Республики" или "на Республике [на улице Республика, - *примеч. редакции*]. Объявить такое просто речевой ошибкой не получается: от затасканных тележурналистами, обретших устойчивость прецедентов типа "на Рублёвке" (район Рублёвского шоссе в Моск. области) это название отличается предельно малой известностью; однако важно *где*, *в какой форме* (устной, письменной) и *в каком контексте*. 
В разговорной речи местных жителей широко практикуется напр. "на Просвещения" (вместо "на проспекте Просвещения"), на Гражданке (в районе Гражданского проспекта), "на Васильевском" (в неформальном разговоре *всегда* опускается "острове") - это примеры ссылок на адрес в Петербурге. Так и с экзотической "Республикой": в устной речи местных жителей можно представить себе оба варианта, которые на слух *не различаются*. При документальном воспроизведении такой речи первый вариант (при официальном "улица Республик**и**") выглядит (для посвящённых, с учётом редакторского уточнения) *разговорным упрощением* (опущено видовое наименование), а второй - просторечным *жаргонизмом* (поскольку название *искажается*; так обычно именуют *рынки*: на Горбушке, на Бессарабке... - если бы не "дом", можно было бы подумать и о блошином рынке "Республика" на одноимённой улице).